# How can I use Serializer for logout?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, logout

I'm very new to Django and preparing for the DRF Session.

I have to write code in Serializers.py and views.py for Logout function but I don't know what to do and where to start.
Can you please help? Here's some code for register and login

## Serialzers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
    
    
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create(
                email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'],)
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
    
            return user
    
    
    class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        email = serializers.CharField(max_length=64)
        password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    
        def validate(self, data): 
            email = data.get("email", None)
            password = data.get("password", None)
    
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                if not user.check_password(password):
                    raise serializers.ValidationError()
                else:
                    return user
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError()
    
    class UserLogoutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        # I have to do this part
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .serializers import *
from .models import *
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response           

class SignUpView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': 'Success', 'data': serializer.data})
        return Response({'message': 'Fail', 'error': serializer.errors})


class LoginView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'message': "Success", 'data': serializer.data})
        return Response({'message': "Fail", 'data': serializer.errors})


class LogoutView(views.APIView):
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily have to use a serializer. Logout can be as simple as calling an endpoint once (logout just disables any active authorization token). Try this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class LogoutView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({'message': "Logout successful"})
```

It depends on how you are authenticating your user. From you code, I do not see how you actually authenticate your user (you only seem to check if the user exists, you do not give them an authorization token anywhere). Basically I am not sure how one would log out in your current architecture as there is no user logged in ever to log them out.

You might want to consider [token authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).